# How to find dependencies on a table in mysql 5.0?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to drop a table in MySQL but its complaining about "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"...

Is there a way to find out all the table dependencies and objects dependent on it?

For sybase, DBArtisan gives a really easy way to find dependecies. Is there any such tool for MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

It'll show you (along with some other stuff) the foreign key relationships for the table.